# react-native-maps marker throwing and IndexOutofBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to get a react-native-maps Marker to show up on my Android device (it work's perfectly fine on iOS) but it's throwing me an IndexOutofBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0 error at render time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Scbw.png

```
render() {
    const INITIAL_REGION = { latitude: 52.221835, longitude: 21.000896, latitudeDelta: 0.0922, longitudeDelta: 0.0421 };
    return (
        <MapView ref="map"
            showsUserLocation = { true }
            loadingEnabled = { true }
            showsTraffic = { false }
            showsBuildings = { false }
            style = { styles.map, {flex: 1} }
            initialRegion = { INITIAL_REGION }
        >
            <View style={{flex: 0.1, flexDirection: 'row', position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                <Button onPress={() => this.showWithinRadius(5)}>Wszystkie ~5km</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => this.showWithinRadius(10)}>Wszystkie ~10km</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => this.showWithinRadius(15)}>Wszystkie ~15km</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => this.showAllOffers()}>Wszystkie oferty</Button>
            </View>
            { console.log(this.state.offerLocation) }
            <Marker
                coordinate = { {latitude: 52.259216308593, longitude: 21.041564941406} }
                title = { this.props.selectedOffer.offer.title }
            />
        </MapView>
    );
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this behaviour? I've tried deleting the View block from the MapView component but that doesn't seem to help. In the actual app I'm planning to pass the coordinates by an object which seem to works in the fitToCoordinates method.

Answer (score 7):

No solutions were given to this issue but it helped me understand and fix mine.
I don't think the `View` is the problem but the order in which the components are rendered.
It seems like, on Android, render order matters. 
So, rendering `Markers` as first child of `MapView` fixed it for me.

It is also mentioned here :
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/291

Hope I'm helping !

Comment: Glad to read that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it was in fact the View component inside the MapView that was causing the issue.

Comment: But I want Show the On Mapview Put in Design City and Search Bar Options How can I Insert

Comment: Would be nice if you explained what was the problem with the View component!

Answer (score 0):

Put the inner View and the market inside one View, this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was removing any view from  (can be a view, an image, etc).
It had no connection to the  object neither to the order.